# Avoid numbers incrementing multiple times when calling a function multiple times

Tags: javascript

I have written a quantity selector function to display on a page. The page can open some modals, which need to have another quantity selector within each.

I am calling the function within the main page, and also within the modal (to enable the functionality once the modal is displayed.)

When I adjust the quantity in the modal, close the modal, and adjust the quantity on the main page, the quantity increments/decrements double (or 3 times if I was to call the function 3 times.)

Is there a way to "reset" each of these event listeners/functions, to only adjust for their respective elements?

I've looked into "removeEventListener" but haven't had any joy in implementing this within my code.

Example of my work so far here (you can see what I mean if you click the buttons.)

https://codepen.io/777333/pen/zYoKYRN

```
const quantitySelector = () => {
  const qtyGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.qty-group');
  if(qtyGroups) {
    qtyGroups.forEach((qtyGroup) => {
      const qtyDecrease = qtyGroup.querySelector('[data-quantity-decrease]');
      const qtyIncrease = qtyGroup.querySelector('[data-quantity-increase]');
      const qtyInput    = qtyGroup.querySelector('[data-quantity-input]');
      const disableEnableDecrease = () => {
        if(qtyInput.value == 1) {
          qtyDecrease.disabled = true;
        } else {
          qtyDecrease.disabled = false;
        }
      };
      qtyDecrease.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(qtyInput.value > 1) {
          qtyInput.value--;
        }
        disableEnableDecrease();
      });
      qtyIncrease.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        qtyInput.value++;
        disableEnableDecrease();
      });
      qtyInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        disableEnableDecrease();
      });
    });
  }
};
quantitySelector(); // called within main page
quantitySelector(); // called within modal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue at hand is that each time you're calling the function, a new event handler is added on top of the previous ones. The best way to avoid this is through Event Delegation where you add a global event handler only once.

```js
// A global event handler
document.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function (event) {
    // Find the qty-group if clicked on it
    const qtyGroup = event.target.closest(".qty-group");
    // Stop if the click was elsewhere
    if (qtyGroup) {
      // Get your elements
      const qtyDecrease = qtyGroup.querySelector("[data-quantity-decrease]");
      const qtyIncrease = qtyGroup.querySelector("[data-quantity-increase]");
      const qtyInput = qtyGroup.querySelector("[data-quantity-input]");
      const disableEnableDecrease = () => {
        if (qtyInput.value == 1) {
          qtyDecrease.disabled = true;
        } else {
          qtyDecrease.disabled = false;
        }
      };
      // Match your elements against what was clicked on.
      if (event.target == qtyDecrease) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (qtyInput.value > 1) {
          qtyInput.value--;
        }
        disableEnableDecrease();
      }

      if (event.target == qtyIncrease) {
        event.preventDefault();
        qtyInput.value++;
        disableEnableDecrease();
      }
    }
  },
  false
);
```

Instead of listening to individual elements, you can capture all the clicks on the document, and then finding those that click on elements of interest. You can make a second event handler for the `keyup` event.

Comment: Just one question, what is the "false" at the end doing here?

Comment: @Matt The false isn't necessary here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener, it disables useCapture.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value of `qtyInput` on `mousedown` event and then in the increment you add or subtract one from the saved value instead of the current value of the input.

```js
const quantitySelector = () => {
  const qtyGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.qty-group');
  if(qtyGroups) {
    qtyGroups.forEach((qtyGroup) => {
      const qtyDecrease = qtyGroup.querySelector('[data-quantity-decrease]');
      const qtyIncrease = qtyGroup.querySelector('[data-quantity-increase]');
      const qtyInput    = qtyGroup.querySelector('[data-quantity-input]');
      const disableEnableDecrease = () => {
        if(qtyInput.value == 1) {
          qtyDecrease.disabled = true;
        } else {
          qtyDecrease.disabled = false;
        }
      };
      let savedValue = null;
      const saveState = (evebt) => savedValue = Number(qtyInput.value);
      qtyDecrease.addEventListener('mousedown', saveState)
      qtyIncrease.addEventListener('mousedown', saveState)
      qtyDecrease.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if(qtyInput.value > 1) {
          qtyInput.value = savedValue - 1;
        }
        disableEnableDecrease();
      });
      qtyIncrease.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        qtyInput.value = savedValue + 1;
        disableEnableDecrease();
      });
      qtyInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        disableEnableDecrease();
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
    });
  }
};
quantitySelector();
quantitySelector();
```

Comment: This is an over-engineering solution to a simple problem.

Comment: under-engineering...
But you have to agree that it is the solution the author asked, it says that the solution must work if the listener was added multiple times. And it can be a legitimate temporary fix. @SlavaKnyazev

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called [`removeEventListener` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) but I suggest you to reshape your code such that you do not add event listener if they are already present.

Put all of your `addEventListener` just when you create your elements, or in a "document ready" callback if they are instantiated by HTML code. Then, when you open your modal, just update your values.

### UPDATING YOUR CODE

```js
// hide/show modal function
function toggleModal() {
  let modal = document.getElementById('modal');
  modal.style.display = modal.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}

// your document ready function
function onReady() {
  const qtyGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.qty-group');
  if(qtyGroups) {
    qtyGroups.forEach((qtyGroup) => {
      const qtyDecrease = qtyGroup.querySelector('[data-quantity-decrease]');
      const qtyIncrease = qtyGroup.querySelector('[data-quantity-increase]');
      const qtyInput    = qtyGroup.querySelector('[data-quantity-input]');
      const disableEnableDecrease = () => {
        if(qtyInput.value == 1) {
          qtyDecrease.disabled = true;
        } else {
          qtyDecrease.disabled = false;
        }
      };
      qtyDecrease.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(qtyInput.value > 1) {
          qtyInput.value--;
        }
        disableEnableDecrease();
      });
      qtyIncrease.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        qtyInput.value++;
        disableEnableDecrease();
      });
      qtyInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
        disableEnableDecrease();
      });
    });
  }
  
  // attach hide/show modal handler
  const toggle = document.getElementById('modal_toggle');
  toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleModal);
}

onReady();
```

```html
<div class="qty-group">
  <button data-quantity-decrease disabled>-</button>
  <input data-quantity-input value="1">
  <button data-quantity-increase>+</button>
</div>

<div class="qty-group" id="modal" style="display: none;">
  <button data-quantity-decrease disabled>-</button>
  <input data-quantity-input value="1">
  <button data-quantity-increase>+</button>
</div>

<button id="modal_toggle">Toggle Modal</button>
```

### REFACTORING

It is better in such cases to reason as **Components**. Components ensure code encapsulation, maintainability, reusage, single responsability and many other usefull principles:

```js
// hide/show modal function
function toggleModal() {
  // get the modal
  let modal = document.getElementById('modal');
  // hide the modal
  modal.style.display = modal.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  // reset the input of the modal
  modalInputReference.reset();
}

function createQuantityInput(target, initialQuantity=1, min=1, max=10, step=1) {
  let quantity = 0;
  
  // assign and check if should be disable, also bind to input value
  let assign = (q) => {
      quantity = Math.max(Math.min(q, max), min);
      decrease.disabled = quantity <= min;
      increase.disabled = quantity >= max;
      input.value = quantity;    
  };
  
  // CREATION
  // This part is not mandatory, you can also get the elements from
  // the target (document.querySelector('button.decrease') or similar)
  // and then attach the listener.
  // Creation is better: ensure encapsulation and single responsability
  
  // create decrease button
  let decrease = document.createElement('button');
  decrease.addEventListener('click', () => { assign(quantity - step); });
  decrease.innerText = '-';
  
  // create increase button
  let increase = document.createElement('button');
  increase.addEventListener('click', () => { assign(quantity + step); });
  increase.innerText = '+'
  
  // create input field
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.value = quantity
  input.addEventListener('change', () => { assign(parseFloat(input.value)); });
  
  // resetting the quantity
  assign(initialQuantity);
  
  // appending the new component to its parent
  target.appendChild(decrease);
  target.appendChild(input);
  target.appendChild(increase);
  
  // return a reference to manipulate this component
  return {
    get quantity() { return quantity; },
    set quantity(q) { assign(q); },
    assign,
    reset: () => assign(initialQuantity)
  };
}

// this will be your modal reference
let modalInputReference;
function onReady() {
  // inject all qty-group with a "quantityInput" component
  document.querySelectorAll('.qty-group').forEach(elem => {
      let input = createQuantityInput(elem);
      if (elem.id == 'modal') {
        // if it is the modal I save it for later use
        // this is just an hack for now,
        // a full code should split this part into a "modal" component maybe 
        modalInputReference = input;
      }
  });
  
  // emualte the modal
  let toggle = document.getElementById('modal_toggle')
  toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleModal)
}

// this function should be wrapped by a
// $(document).ready(onReady) or any other
// function that ensure that all the DOM is successfully loaded
// and the code is not executed before the browser has generated
// all the elements present in the HTML
onReady();
```

```html
<div class="qty-group"></div>
<div class="qty-group" id="modal" style="display: none;"></div>

<button id="modal_toggle">Toggle Modal</button>
```

It is shorter (without comments) and also more maintenable. Don't trust who says it is overengineered, it is just kind of time to learn to reason this way, then is much easier and faster. It is just a time investment to waste less time in the future. Try figure out why React or Angular(JS) have climbed the charts of the best frameworks so fast.